# What are modes in which you can open file in python?

Tags: python, file

When you open file like that:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
f.write("Something")
```

Answer (score -1):

> There are some in which you can open file.

```
"r"   Opens a file for reading only.
"r+"  Opens a file for both reading and writing.
"rb"  Opens a file for reading only in binary format.
"rb+" Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format.
"w"   Opens a file for writing only.
"a"   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.
"a+"  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.
"x" Creates a new file. If file already exists, the operation fails.
"t" This is the default mode. It opens in text mode.
"b" This opens in binary mode.
"+" This will open a file for reading and writing (updating)
```